# grep doesn't show result

Tags: shell, grep, man

I was trying to search in `man find`, and I would like to know what's going on.

```sh
$ man find | grep Like
             Like -lname, but the match is case insensitive.  This is a GNU
             Like -name, but the match is case insensitive.
             Like -path, but the match is case insensitive.
             Like -regex, but the match is case insensitive.
             Like -name, but the contents of the symbolic link are matched
$ man find | grep "\-name"
     find / \! -name "*.c" -print
     find /usr/src -name CVS -prune -o -depth +6 -print
     find /usr/src -name CVS -prune -o -mindepth 7 -print
$ man find | grep "name,"
             and there is no such group name, then gname is treated as a group
             and there is no such user name, then uname is treated as a user
```

What's going on? How come I can see lines that contain `-name,` but I don't get those results if I search for `-name` or `name,` and why does that show different things? I imagine it has to do with some “metadata” in man page not shown in the terminal, but I don't know.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: In my debian , using `gnu grep 3.3` , the results of `grep 'name'` are much more compared to `grep '\-name'` and includes all the results provided by `'\-name'`. I suppose this behavior you encounter is in your grep implementation.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I used `grep 'name,'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default formatting from the man page (such as for bold words) is done by interspersing control characters and letters (and the control characters aren't easily visible in the output).

```
$ grep 'This is a GNU' /tmp/find.out
             Like -lname, but the match is case insensitive.  This is a GNU
$ grep 'This is a GNU' /tmp/find.out | od -c
0000000                                                        L   i   k
0000020    e       -  \b   -   l  \b   l   n  \b   n   a  \b   a   m  \b
0000040    m   e  \b   e   ,       b   u   t       t   h   e       m   a
0000060    t   c   h       i   s       c   a   s   e       i   n   s   e
0000100    n   s   i   t   i   v   e   .           T   h   i   s       i
0000120    s       a       G   N   U  \n
```

You can see the backspace/overstrike pairs in the -name word.  It looks fine when printed, but means that `name` isn't a sequence of characters in the output.